# Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key', details={}}.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

We have recently moved to mongo java driver core/sync 4.4.0 from 3.12.1 with spring data mongo db from 2.2.5.RELEASE to 3.3.0 also spring boot version 2.6.2 and mongo server version 4.2.5

We are getting exceptions while hitting upsert queries on sharded collection with above mentioned error

There is way to insert shard key in query filter but that is not feasible for us, hence we tried adding @Sharded annotations to our DTO as we have different shard keys for different collections

Still we are getting the above mentioned error also we are unable to get exact meaning of what is full copy of entity meant in below statement

update/upsert operations replacing/upserting a single existing document as long as the given UpdateDefinition holds a full copy of the entity.

Other queries are working fine also upsert queries are working fine on addition of shard key in query filter but that change is not feasible for us we need quick solution

Please help as not able to find any solution on any platform. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The other queries that are working are also using upsert? And are they running on the sharded collection as well?

Comment: Nope I was trying to say that there's is no issue with overall mongo upgrade and other query execution but only upsert specific queries are getting failed.

Comment: Can you confirm that if your `upsert` queries on the sharded collections?

Comment: Yes upsert queries are on sharded collections

Comment: It's hard to say what's causing the error without knowledge about the involved domain objects nor the update issued against the server. Can you please update the description and/or ideally provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

So here's the deal:

You cannot `upsert` on Sharded Collection in MongoDB **UNLESS** you include the shard key in the filter provided for update operation.

To quote MongoDB Docs:

> For a db.collection.update() operation that includes upsert: true and is on a sharded collection, you must include the full shard key in the filter:
>
> 1. For an update operation.
> 2. For a replace document operation (starting
>    in MongoDB 4.2).

If you are using MongoDB 4.4+ then you have a workaround as mentioned below:

> However, starting in version 4.4, documents in a sharded collection can be missing the shard key fields. To target a document that is missing the shard key, you can use the null equality match in conjunction with another filter condition (such as on the _id field). For example:

```
{ _id: <value>, <shardkeyfield>: null } // _id of the document missing shard key
```

Ref: - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#behavior

Comment: Hii Gobind,Thanks for the information. Can @Sharded annotation be used to resolve this issue as mentioned in below documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Sharded.html.    If yes, how to use it as adding it to DTO is not resolving the issue

Comment: From the link you mentioned - Spring Data adds the shard key to filter queries used for update/upsert operations replacing/upserting a single existing document as long as the given UpdateDefinition holds a full copy of the entity.

Is that the case with you?

Comment: I didn't understood the exact meaning of the sentence "as long as the given UpdateDefinition holds a full copy of the entity" means the UpdateDefinition must have all the fields from that collection in $set clause or anything else ?

Comment: Yes you can try that. P.S. I am a MongoDB expert and not really a JAVA expert. From MongoDB perspective I will highly recommend following the fixes recommended in my answer